# DART: How to get list from a Future class when being imported form another file?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class InvernaderoManager {
  final GSheets _gsheets = GSheets(_credentials);
  Spreadsheet _spreadsheet;
  Worksheet _invernaderoSheet;

  Future<void> init() async {
    _spreadsheet ??= await _gsheets.spreadsheet(_spreadsheetId);
    _invernaderoSheet ??= await _spreadsheet.worksheetByTitle('invernadero');
  }

  Future<List<Product>> getAll() async {
    await init();
    final invernadero = await _invernaderoSheet.values.allRows(fromRow: 2);
    return List.generate(
        invernadero.length,
            (index) =>
            Product(
              bomba: invernadero[index][2],
              nivel: int.tryParse(invernadero[index][3] ?? ''),
              temp: int.tryParse(invernadero[index][4] ?? ''),
              ph: int.tryParse(invernadero[index][5] ?? ''),
              ec: int.tryParse(invernadero[index][6] ?? ''),
            ));
  }
}
```

I want to import the resulting  list of the Future class, I'm trying with `var inver = InvernaderoManager().getAll();` but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: it doesn't give me the list of values from the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an instance of class InvernaderoManager and then call a method with 'await' keyword. So, something like should work :

```
InvernaderoManager invernaderoManager = new InvernaderoManager();

var inver = await invernaderoManager.getAll();
```

Comment: I get two errors with your solution. 
await give me error: The await expression can only be used in an async function. 
invernaderoManager.getAll(); error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Comment: await give me error: The await expression can only be used in an async function. invernaderoManager.getAll(); error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Comment: That's probably because you are using 'await' keyword in non-async function. Check if [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) link helps.

Comment: `class SearchTrips extends StatelessWidget {
Future<void> data() async {
    InvernaderoManager invernaderoManager = new InvernaderoManager();
    return await invernaderoManager.getAll();
  } `
I am using the code you gave me on another file class, I dont get any errors but I dont know how to access the list given on the return

Comment: The definition of `data()` is wrong. You said `Future<void>` but you are returning the data from getAll(). Instead of returning, just check if you get anything in variable `inver`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Future builder

declare your class like this:

```
class InvernaderoManager {
}
final invernaderoManager = InvernaderoManager ();
```

And build your widget using future builder:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
      future: invernaderoManager.getAll(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Product>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
// build your widget here
          return buildMain(context, snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: This goes on the same file I have my class right?

How can I get the data on another file I am importing my class InvernaderoManager()??